# How to search through multiple large files without your cpu getting crazy?

Tags: java

So my question is, how can i search through multiple files which are around 500 mb, as fast as possible of course but also as less as possible cpu usage, there is a second requirement:
the function has to be able to return the line the searched text is on, so not only knowing the text is in the file, or multiple times in the file, but also return the line in which the searched text occurs.

thanks in advance, blackwolf12333

Comment: This will almost certainly be limited by disk performance, not CPU performance.

Comment: Hmm, ok, but my cpu went crazy when i tried it using a BufferedReader and then use: line = br.readLine() != null

Comment: Can't tell you what's wrong without seeing some code.

Comment: there isn't anything wrong, i just don't know how to do something like this:P

Comment: For the record, on my OS X, 64-bit Java 1.6, `readLine` was CPU-limited: `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")); String line; for (int i = 0; (line = in.readLine()) != null; i++) if (line.indexOf("a1oe") != -1) System.out.println(i);` (didn't print anything, the file had no matches for the string).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create in inverted index and search on that. The creation takes little bit more time but it is just a one time expense. After the index creation the search's are super fast. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) is the popular open-source library that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) indexers for fast search. If you don't want big library as Lucene, you can create indexes for searching manually, it isn't hard.

Comment: How would i do that? I am not that experienced in this kind of things:P

Comment: Depends on what sort of data should you find. For example you just need find the count of specified word in document. You perform full scan on the document and save number of occurences of each word in the map. This process called indexing and created map is called index. After that you can detect count of specified word by using index instead of document. For other functionality you can save more complicated information in index.